# Understanding Git, working with a php ide and ftp

Tags: php, git, ide, ftp, workspace

In my past projects I have failed to invest time in setting up my workspace correctly.

For backups + version control I simply copy my webdirectory files to a separate folder on my hard-disk, if I find I have made a mistake somewhere, I reload a previous backup and start again from that point, often wasting precious time repeating work I have already done.

My IDE has no ftp functionality, I have to manually copy the files from my desktop to my webserver, constantly overwriting files and duplicating.

I am certain there is a better, more efficient way of doing the above. I have read about Git for version control and know I should be using it.

What is the suggested way to work efficiently (OS is Windows) with an IDE, version control and FTP that will save me sweat, tears and data loss?

EDIT: I am currently using netbeans IDE

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Could help for integration options.

Comment: Hi melee, I am using netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how my setup works - this may or may not be feasible for you, but I hope it helps somehow. I no longer use FTP for anything.

You should get a DVCS setup, and which one you choose is entirely up to you. Any of them will be better than manually copying or not having anything at all. I suggest taking a look at both Git and Mercurial and making a decision from there. In my opinion, if you're using Windows primarily, Mercurial might be a better choice. If not, I'd say go for Git. You could always try both!

I setup a [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) server which acts as a central repository for all of my git projects. It is great to have a remote central repository because your entire codebase is backed up in the case that your workstation should fail - and on top of that, you can use it to do some code coordination to move your files around (and stop using FTP).

Once that is setup, I start the process of `pull`ing and `push`ing to it - you talk about your IDE here, and there are a lot of Git IDE options, but I just use the command line - I just find it faster. Again, up to you on how to incorporate that.

In terms of web development, I setup my gitolite server to use git-hooks to propagate changes to my servers. They all have the `git` client installed, so the codebase is usually in the webroot. When a change is pushed from my workstation to the gitolite server, it fires off some commands that automatically updates the production server. Not only is it convenient, but it also puts a copy of the codebase and its versions on your servers as well. Be careful with this though; you need to make sure you aren't sharing your `/.git` directory.

The basic idea is to improve your development ecosystem. My Git setup is perfect for that. You might need to assess your entire workflow and make adjustments based on your needs.

[Here's the `git` plugin for NetBeans.](http://nbgit.org/) I suggest using the command line when you get started, though.

Comment: Where would I setup a Gitolite server?? Would I need a dedicated server?? Are there free repositories that won't share my code?

Comment: You would have to set it up yourself, and ideally in either a dedicated server or VM - if that seems like overkill, I'd checkout https://github.com/ :)

Comment: What would be the chances of somebody finding my code on github if using the free version?

Comment: That I can't answer with confidence. I don't use GitHub, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Version control - when used properly - is *much* better than simply copying files around. In a single user environment, version control allows you to have fine-grain control over your versioning, often in a way that is more space efficient than full file copies because the old versions are stored as diffs.

In a multi-developer environment, version control provides the same benefits, but you also have to consider the case when multiple people edit the same file at the same time. In the simplest case, two people edit the same file in different places and you can safely take both modifications in sequence. In more complex cases, two or more developers make changes to the same region of code and it needs to be manually merged.

Git is different from traditional revision control systems in that it was designed to be used in a distributed fashion. That is - each developer has their own repository, and merges happen when they need to happen. You can have an authoritative central server if you want one, but you don't need to make very commit to that server all the time. This makes git particularly suitable to individual or remote development. Git doesn't require a heavy server on your desktop, just one small binary.

There are a lot of tutorials out there on git. Some of them are:

- [Getting into SCM with git](http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~sxanth/ungit.html)
- [github's](http://github.com) [Introduciton to Git](http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html)
- [A Visual Git Reference](http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/index-en.html)
- [Git Tutorial](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/git/)